# Github throws OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError

Tags: github, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I am trying to integrate github authentication with a rails application using

`omniauth-github-1.1.0` and `rails-3.2.12 gems`

Every time I try to authenticate my app using Github I get this error:

`"OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError" with URL -`
`http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/github/callback/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch`

Application is registered with:
URL - `http://127.0.0.1:3000`
Callback URL - `http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/github/callback/`

Omniauth initialzer file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET']
end
```

I have double checked the GITHUB_KEY, GITHUB_SECRET. Can't really see any reason for authentication to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `localhost:3000` for running the app and expecting the callback to work. But I should have used `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` instead.

Comment: This is exactly it. Thanks.